# How to select multiple classes onclick and change the colours when selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner using tutorials to learn how to apply different colours to different parts of products.

How do I highlight multiple classes on click and change the colour of the selected boxes, instead of only one box?
For example, when selecting a box, I can select not just a single class, but multiple class, then change multiple classes as the same color?

```js
let overlay;
document.querySelectorAll('#product-a, #product-b, #product-c').forEach(function(path) {
  path.onclick = chooseProduct;
})


function chooseProduct(e) {
  if (overlay) overlay.classList.remove('highlight')
  overlay = e.target
  overlay.classList.add('highlight')
}
var removeHighlight = function(e) {
  var products = document.querySelectorAll('.product');

  if (!e.target.classList.contains('product') && !e.target.classList.contains('color')) {
    overlay = null;
    document.querySelectorAll('.product').forEach(function(prod) {
      prod.classList.remove('highlight');
    });
  }
}

document.onclick = removeHighlight;
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("color");
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].onclick = changeColor;
}

function changeColor(e) {
  let hex = e.target.getAttribute("data-hex");
  overlay.style.fill = hex;
}
```

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#product-svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

path {
  fill: #CCCCCC;
}

.colors {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2em;
  right: 2em;
  z-index: 3;
}

.color {
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.highlight {
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <svg id="product-svg" viewBox="0 0 744 1074">
      <path id="product-a" class="product" d="M51 207.5L51 348L686 348L686 67L51 67L51 207.5Z" />
      <path id="product-b" class="product" d="M51 544.5L51 685L686 685L686 404L51 404L51 544.5Z" />
      <path id="product-c" class="product" d="M51 883.5L51 1024L686 1024L686 743L51 743L51 883.5Z" />

    </svg>
  <img id="background-image" src="boxes.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="colors">
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #ff0000" data-hex="#ff0000"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #ffff33" data-hex="#ffff33"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #3399ff" data-hex="#3399ff"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Is this what you want: `document.querySelectorAll('.class1, .class2, .class3');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a code that add the boxes to an array as the user clicks on them. That way, the selected ones will be contained in that array. I think this solves your problem:

```js
const overlays = [];
document.querySelectorAll('#product-a, #product-b, #product-c').forEach(function(path) {
  path.onclick = chooseProduct;
})


function chooseProduct(e) {
  overlays.push(e.target);
  overlays.forEach((overlay) => overlay.classList.add('highlight'));
}
var removeHighlight = function(e) {
    var products = document.querySelectorAll('.product');

    if(!e.target.classList.contains('product') && !e.target.classList.contains('color')){
        overlays.length = 0;
        document.querySelectorAll('.product').forEach(function(prod){
            prod.classList.remove('highlight');
        });
    }
}

document.onclick = removeHighlight;
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("color");
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].onclick = changeColor;
}
function changeColor(e) {
  let hex = e.target.getAttribute("data-hex");
  overlays.forEach((overlay) => overlay.style.fill = hex);
}
```

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;

}

#product-svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

path {
  fill: #CCCCCC;
}

.colors {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2em;
  right: 2em;
  z-index: 3;
}

.color {
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.highlight {
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

    <svg id="product-svg" viewBox="0 0 744 1074">
      <path id="product-a" class="product" d="M51 207.5L51 348L686 348L686 67L51 67L51 207.5Z" />
      <path id="product-b" class="product" d="M51 544.5L51 685L686 685L686 404L51 404L51 544.5Z" />
      <path id="product-c" class="product" d="M51 883.5L51 1024L686 1024L686 743L51 743L51 883.5Z" />

    </svg>
    <img id="background-image" src="boxes.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="colors">
    <div class="color" style="background-color: #ff0000" data-hex="#ff0000"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: #ffff33" data-hex="#ffff33"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: #3399ff" data-hex="#3399ff"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind, but can you explain a bit more about the - var removeHighlight = function(e) section please, thanks.

Comment: Sure. The only change I've made in that function was replacing `overlay: null` for      overlays.length = 0. That's because "overlays" is an array, so, when removing highlight, I empty it by giving the value 0 to the length property. You can't assign null to the array because, otherwise, an error would be thrown when trying to push a "product" into it.